# change solc version

Tags: solidity, truffle

for some reason I am having trouble upgrading the truffle solidity compiler version.  truffle version --> Truffle v5.2.2
Solidity v0.5.16
When I uninstall and re-install truffle (npm uninstall -g truffle and npm install -g truffle) it is the same version.  How do I use a more recent version of Solidity with Truffle?  On windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I did find the correct method I believe is to modify the truffle-config.js.  This works for me.

```
    }, //make sure you have the comma here 
    compilers: {
        solc: {
            version: "0.4.22", // ex:  "0.4.20". (Default: Truffle's installed solc)
        },
    },
```